# Score counter using PHP and JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript

If I want to add a score counter to my website. for example if the user answers a question then it will be saved in a database and the correct answer is already saved in the same database table. I want to make a comparison  between the answers. if the answer is correct the score raises.

I am planning to code the score counter by using JAVASCRIPT. How can I call the javascript function within PHP.

If I do like that:

```
<?php
if($_SESSION['Correct_answer'] == $_SESSION['User_answer'])
echo "<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='javascript'>" echo count() "</SCRIPT>";
```

And the javascript function looks like:

```
<script>
var x=0;
function count(){
x+=1;
document.getElementById( "counting" ).value =  x;
}
```

Where "counting" is a text field.
When I tried to use this code it didn't work. Is the above code correct???

Thank you in advance.

Edited:

Ok I did what u said but i still have a problem when refreshing the page the score increases by one. How can I stop the increasing of score when reloading the page???

Here is my code:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['score']))
   $_SESSION['score'] = 0;


else{
$sql10=mysql_query("select * from image WHERE fromUser='".$_SESSION['email']."' order by id desc");
$score1=mysql_fetch_array($sql10);
$answer=$score1['answer'];

$sql13=mysql_query("select * from image WHERE toUser='".$_SESSION['email']."' order by id desc");
$score2=mysql_fetch_array($sql13);
$answer2=$score2['answer2'];


strcasecmp($answer,$answer2);
if(strcasemp)
$_SESSION['score'] += 1;
}
```

Comment: You can't do this. PHP code runs at the server before the webpage is sent to the browser. JavaScript code runs in the browser. Your text box JavaScript is keeping the count in will be empty as each new page loads, it won't remember what was in there on a previous page load itself.

Comment: Are you calling your PHP with Ajax? If you aren't I don't see any reason for using javascript.

Comment: @Amal the `LANGUAGE`keyword is deprecated. use `<script type="text/javascript">... </script>`

Answer (score 0):

Server-side PHP and client-side JavaScript cannot call one another directly like that. All of this logic should be in PHP. You probably want something like this (I'm assuming you want to store the score in $_SESSION as well).

```
<?php
if (!isset($_SESSION['score'])
    $_SESSION['score'] = 0;

if ($_SESSION['Correct_answer'] == $_SESSION['User_answer'])
    $_SESSION['score'] += 1;
?>
<p>Current score: <?= $_SESSION['score'] ?></p>
```

You see, server-side code (like PHP) is run on your web server, whereas JavaScript is run in the browser. The server and the browser communicate only through the HTTP requests you issue, so PHP and JavaScript functions cannot call each other as you are trying to do.

Comment: I edited my code can u please take a look to see how to fix the problem and thank you for your help.